# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. when integrating projects

Tags: android

I am getting same error every-time I add the following files in gradle.

Error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        renderscriptTargetApi 22
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
    compile project(':androidHorizontalListView')
    compile 'com.ocpsoft:ocpsoft-pretty-time:1.0.6'
    compile project(':httpclientandroidlib-1.1.2')
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.7.2'
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:1.2.0@aar'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:1.0.5'
    compile 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.2.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'

    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.0.1'
}
```

I don't know how I can resolve the error.I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has to be a jar file being compiled twice, either add each jar in your libs folder individually:

```
compile files('libs/yourjarfile.jar')
```

rather than:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

or determine the file in your libs folder that is being compiled twice, and remove it keeping the fileTree compilation. Your best bet would probably be to do what I say with compiling each file individually, then looking to see the duplication in the gradle file

Comment: So how can I do that or in other words where can I see all jar files in android studio?Can you please guide me ?Thanks a lot for your time.I really appreciate your help.

Comment: there is a libs folder in your project directory, where you have a bunch of jars you are trying to compile. this line: compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs') is going through and compiling all those jars, while you are also importing jars from mvn with lines like: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'. Android studio should have your files on the left side of the screen in your 'app' folder or w/e you named it

Comment: Is there a way to check which jar file is repeated or giving me this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think I also experienced similar problem.

You are using the latest `appcompat-v7 22.2.1`:

```
dependencies {
    (...)
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    (...)
}
```

Then maybe you should use the same version of `CardView` and `RecyclerView`.

```
dependencies {
    (...)
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    (...)
}
```

At least for me this solution worked.

Comment: @jason Then my answer is pointless, sorry. Lucas Crawford's answer may be proper.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the jar files and dependencies and clean project .Now add one by one each jar file and also remove 
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) .Now Sync,clean and rebuild.Done.